# Transection in Fragments in android studio using java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there any way to create transactions in fragments by sliding the screen as well as touching the fragments in android studio using java? Like in WhatsApp transactions can be done by touching chat, status, or call as well as it is done by sliding the screen left and right.

Comment: You should use the ViewPager: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: Thanks for this link. It's helped me a lot and I have created my fragments in both swapping and on the tab. @Mieczkoni